# Using Select Layer By Attribute in Python Script Tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, python-script-tool

I just want to try to use a Python script to select specific roads in my Layer called "Route_01_Shatin" and so I coded as below:

```
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('Route_01_Shatin', 'NEW_SELECTION', "\"ALIAS_ENAM\" = \'Roadabout\'")
```

but then when I ran it, I did not receive any error messages but none of the roads are selected.

What is my problem?

Comment: Does that field have values of Roadabout or might they be Roundabout?

Comment: You don't need to escape single-quotes inside a double-quote string.

Comment: Does it work if you select by attributes using the same clause in Pro directly, without a script?  Is the layer in a shapefile or database?

Answer (score 0):

If your field named ALIAS_ENAM of your layer named Route_01_Shatin has any values of 'Roadabout', then I think this should work:

```
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('Route_01_Shatin', 'NEW_SELECTION', "ALIAS_ENAM = 'Roadabout'")
```